# Getting a File's MD5 Checksum in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk, md5

How to calculate the md5 for a specific file in a Javascript?

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
    <script>
    var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("c23a340c2299871541d8a9d2e47bd7d5.wmv");
    alert(hash);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a sample code so in this we can get the MD5 for a sorting; only I found like these examples several but I want it for a specific file like the below link will give the md5 for a file:
[This link will calculate the md5 for a file so like this I want the Javascript to calculate the md5 for a file](https://md5file.com/calculator)

Answer (score 0):

From my small understanding of hashing functions, what your code is doing is giving the hash of the string, which you have stated.  For it to hash the contents of the file, you would want to read the file into a byte stream (not sure if that is the correct terminology), and hash the resulting bytes.

Below is a snippet of their JS code to show how they load the file into a byte stream.

```
/*
 * (c) 2011 by md5file.com. All rights reserved.
 */
function hash_file(file, workers) {
  var i, buffer_size, block, threads, reader, blob, handle_hash_block, handle_load_block;

  handle_load_block = function (event) {
    for( i = 0; i < workers.length; i += 1) {
      threads += 1;
      workers[i].postMessage({
        'message' : event.target.result,
        'block' : block
      });
    }
  };
  handle_hash_block = function (event) {
    threads -= 1;

    if(threads === 0) {
      if(block.end !== file.size) {
        block.start += buffer_size;
        block.end += buffer_size;

        if(block.end > file.size) {
          block.end = file.size;
        }
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = handle_load_block;
        blob = file.slice(block.start, block.end);

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
      }
    }
  };
  buffer_size = 64 * 16 * 1024;
  block = {
    'file_size' : file.size,
    'start' : 0
  };

  block.end = buffer_size > file.size ? file.size : buffer_size;
  threads = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < workers.length; i += 1) {
    workers[i].addEventListener('message', handle_hash_block);
  }
  reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = handle_load_block;
  blob = file.slice(block.start, block.end);

  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As NotAPro [guessed](//stackoverflow.com/questions/23291603/getting-a-files-md5-checksum-in-javascript/23293941#23293941), to get a checksum of a file, the local executing browser and its JS engine needs to read the file contents and that is only possible with the following requirements:

- File and FileReader APIs [which are only supported by later browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader).

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ is a guide how to do it. It has additional dependencies on FileList and Blob APIs but i presume those come along with the File API.

By the way, i saw this question looking for a checksum method (for a simple email address in a cookie) and i will use the SHA-256 algorithm of
http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/scripts.html.
There, Paul also includes a contributed `sha1_stream()` source that would be food for hack on file/byte stream operations.

If perfectness is a concern i remind you that MD5 and SHA1 are broken.